# How to list all possible ways to pair up a list?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and need to list all possible ways to pair up (even) lists of Ints.

E.g.

```
[1,2,3,4] -> [[(1,2),(3,4)], [(2,3),(1,4)], [(1,3),(2,4)],  ...]
```

Generating all possible pairs is easy enough (shown below) but I can't work out how to return only ways to pair up the entire input list.

```
pairs :: [a] -> [[(a, a)]]
pairs l = [(x,y) | (x:ys) <- tails l, y <- ys]
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend writing a function that nondeterministically chooses an element, returning the rest of the values in the list as well. There are a few possible APIs; the one I suggest below is the most general-purpose one, and one I've used on many occasions for apparently unrelated tasks.

```
zippers :: [a] -> [([a], a, [a])]
```

Here's an example of what this function does:

```
> zippers "abcd"
[("", 'a', "bcd"), ("a", 'b', "cd"), ("ba", 'c', "d"), ("cba", 'd', "")]
```

Once you have that, you can simply repeatedly non-deterministically choose an element from the ever-shrinking list of available options, making a pair after every other choice.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm struggling to implement it, do you perhaps have an example you could show?

Comment: @xavrr No, the next step is yours. After you've spent some time with it, you should either have it, or have the seed for a good, new question showing what you tried, why you're stuck, and why you think it's not possible to make progress.

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of a helper function `pick` that returns a list of 2-tuples with as first element the item picked, and a second element a list of remaining elements:

```
pick :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
pick [] = []
pick (x:xs) = (x, xs) : …
```

where the `…` part should make a call to `pick` with the tail of the list, and prepend each second item of the 2-tuples returned with `x`.

With this `pick` function we can then construct all combinations with:

```
pairs :: [a] -> [[(a, a)]]
pairs [] = [[]]
pairs (x:xs) = [(x,y):tl | (y, zs) <- pick xs, tl <- pairs zs]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm not 100% sure what the ... is meant to be, specifically the part about prepending the 2-tuples with x?

Comment: @xavrr: `pick [1,2]` is supposed to return `[(1, [2]), (2, [1])]`. But if you make a recursive call on the tail of the list, you get `[(1, [2]), (2, [])]`. You thus need to prepend the `1` for all items in the tail to the second item of the 2-tuples